# How to make statements effect after a change event was fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select element in a form with id of "qlt". 
And if I change the value of that selection, other SELECT(#names) element changes its option(s).

However, it seems the change function takes effect at the moment I tick the dropdown, not after the value has changed.

So my jquery code condition below has an opposite effect. If the value of qlt is 14-1, then the selection will have "Hello (90x55mm)" as its option insted of Business Card (90x55mm.

```
var qlt = (jQuery("#qlt").val()).split(":")[0];    

jQuery('#qlt').change(function(){   
    if(qlt=="14-1"){
        ChangeOptions(["Business Card (90x55mm)"],"#names",[1]);
    }
    else if(qlt=="14-2"){
        ChangeOptions(["Hello (90x55mm)"],"#names",[2]);
    }
});


jQuery('#names').change(function(){
    quantities=[50,100,250,500,1000,2000,5000];
    ChangeOptions(quantities,"#qlnt",quantities);
});
```

If my question is not clear, you can visit  the actual site here:
`http://210.48.94.218/~printabl/products/labels-stickers/`

The two select elements I am referring to are the Quality and Size dropdowns. The form is in the middle.

Comment: where is `qlt` declared?

Comment: its a global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem looks like the order of callback execution

The `qlt` variable is set using the method `calculate` which is registered using `jQuery("select").change(calculate);` at line 701.
But the change options callback is registered at line 528 which will get executed before the `calculate` method is called that is why the value of `qlt` is not updated until next select.

One solution is to move `jQuery("select").change(calculate);` before line 528 another one is below

It might be a problem of some script execution, I assume `qlt` is supposed to be the current selected value in the `#qlt` input then you can declare a local variable and assign the current value using `$(this).val()`

```
jQuery('#qlt').change(function(){   
    var qlt = $(this).val().split(":")[0];
    if(qlt=="14-1"){
        ChangeOptions(["Business Card (90x55mm)"],"#names",[1]);
    }
    else if(qlt=="14-2"){
        ChangeOptions(["Hello (90x55mm)"],"#names",[2]);
    }
});
```